# Validation for columns work very slow (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-profiling

I want to perform data profiling on the columns of a table. In this particular case - what percentage of data is date/integer/numeric/bit. The query that I am using:

```
SELECT 
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN TRY_CAST([column1] AS date) IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS date) between '1950-01-01' AND '2049-12-31' AND LEN(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX)))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))/(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [column1] IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) not IN ('null', 'n/a') AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))+0.00000001) AS PercentDate,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN TRY_CAST([column1] AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL AND LEN(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX)))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))/(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [column1] IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) not IN ('null', 'n/a') AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))+0.00000001) AS PercentNumeric,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN TRY_CAST([column1] AS BIGINT) IS NOT NULL AND LEN(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX)))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))/(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [column1] IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) not IN ('null', 'n/a') AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))+0.00000001) AS PercentInteger,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(TRY_CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))) IN ('1', '0', 't', 'f', 'y', 'n', 'true', 'false', 'yes', 'no') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))/(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [column1] IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) not IN ('null', 'n/a') AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX))))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))+0.00000001) AS PercentBit
    FROM tbl
```

This query works really slow even if I choose only top 1 row. Actually I am not able to get any result, or at least I cannot wait such a long time.
The column that I am checking is of type decimal if this is of any importance.

[image]

The number of records in the table is: 37,431,866. This is why I choose only top 1000 for example, but still does not load any result for more than 40 minutes

Comment: Please add details about the execution plan (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan-in-sql-server), and the DDL for the table `tbl`.  How many records are in that table?

Comment: I have edited it in my question

Comment: Do you have a DDL (the create table statement for this table).  Because of the `SUM(...)` the complete table has to be read., so doing `TOP 1000` will not help.

Comment: Try `SELECT ... FROM (select top(1000) * from tbl) t` to limit a scan range. Any `varchar(max)` columns or something?

Comment: No, I don't have DDL. I don't have permissions. But the `SUM (...)` part sounds like the problem. Is there a way I can transform this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to run faster, then you don't want to limit the rows in the query you are using.  After all, an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` only returns one row.

Instead use a subquery:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT TOP (1000) t.*
      FROM tbl t
     ) t
```

Note that this is *not* a random sample.  And if you attempt `ORDER BY newid()` you will kill performance.  One alternative to get an approximate n% sample is to use logic like this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT TOP (1000) t.*
      FROM tbl t
      WHERE RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) < 0.001
     ) t
```

The 0.001 would be about a 0.1% sample.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your solution. Now the problem stays, what happens if I want to check the whole table? Will I have to wait an eternity to get result?

Comment: You example with `RAND ...` returns null values.

Comment: @Yana . . . Wow!  I knew that construct was a less than perfect random number generator, but I didn't realize it was that bad:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a182662e35708e8a0f0833b50b8e9a8f.

Comment: I really don't understand your cte and what you mean with it. I am sorry. And `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) ` returns NULL, if I substitute `NEWID()` with `0` I get a result.

Comment: @Yana . . . That expression should be returning a random number between 0 and 1.  The db<>fiddle shows that in 1000 rows, it is not even generating a value less than 0.1.  That is not very random.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be simpliefied. The part:

`CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN TRY_CAST([column1] AS date) IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS date) between '1950-01-01' AND '2049-12-31' AND LEN(RTRIM(CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(MAX)))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))`

can alo be written as:

`CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN  TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS date) between '1950-01-01' AND '2049-12-31'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUMERIC(25,2))`

The second one is quicker then the first one, with the same result. (AFAIK)

This probably can also be applied to the other parts in the query.